# Received Authentication Denied as Response while trying to get the access token (for Cloudhub.io) with requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, mulesoft, cloudhub

I'm tying to get the data from the Cloudhub API which resides on Mulesoft.

I tried to access through postman (With the same Client Credentials - Bearer Authorization) and it's working fine (I can able to get the result with proper get requests).

But when I **tried to do the same with Python** `requests` library I ran into issues. Here is my piece of code:

```
import requests
import json, os
CLIENT_ID = os.environ['CLIENT_ID']
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET']
grant_type = 'client_credentials'
body_params = {'grant_type' : grant_type}
headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
           'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Content-Type':'application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
url='https://<domain-name>-api.us-w2.cloudhub.io/api/token'
response = requests.post(url, data=body_params, auth = (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET), headers= headers)
token_raw = json.loads(response.text)
print(token_raw)
```

> **Result:** {'error': 'Authentication denied.'}

All I need to know is
How it's working fine with Postman but why I'm not able to connect with python code?

Is there anything I've to change in my code or any additional information needed for this request? or **am I passing the correct endpoint** in receiving the access token for Cloudhub API?

Please post your suggestions or any documentation that I need to refer.
Hope the information that I gave is clear and Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Are you trying to get a token from your application deployed in CloudHub, or an Anypoint Platform token to use with the CloudHub REST API? Your example seems to imply the former, but your comment mentions CloudHub API. Please clarify. Also attach the Postman example, however not as a screenshot which are usually useless, but using the 'Code' feature to generate a Python equivalent. Are you certain the credentials are Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question. [I can get it from the postman itself.](https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/docapis_curl_with_petstore.html#export-postman-to-curl)

Here is my code for API Call with Python.

```
import http.client
import os
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("<domain-name>-api.us-w2.cloudhub.io")
payload = ''
headers = {
  'client_id': os.environ['CLIENT_ID'],
  'client_secret': os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET']
}
conn.request("GET", "/api/<Query that you want to pass - endpoint>", payload, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
resp_data = response.read()
print(resp_data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Note that that's is not a token from Anypoint Platform to use with CloudHub API. It is a request to some application that is deployed to CloudHub using client id and secret. The Authentication header must be ignored, since it doesn't have a token value after the 'Bearer' string. There is no token at all.

Comment: Upvoted ! thanks for update and contribution, will work as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is incorrect. To call CloudHub REST API you need to [obtain a bearer token from Anypoint Platform REST API](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-generate-your-Authorization-Bearer-token-for-Anypoint-Platform). The URL mentioned looks to for some application deployed in CloudHub, not from the platform APIs. This is the same method than [to get the bearer token to use in Anypoint MQ Admin API](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/mq-apis#mqadminapi). It looks like you are trying to use the Anypoint MQ Broker API, which is an Anypoint MQ specific token.

Example in Curl to get an Anypoint Platform token:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"joe.blogs","password":"sample.password"}' https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login
{
"access_token": "f648eea2-3704-4560-bb46-bfff79712652",
"token_type": "bearer",
"redirectUrl": "/home/"
}
```

Additionally the Content-type of your example seems incorrect because it has 2 values.

I'm sure the Postman request is different for it to work, or maybe it works only for the Anypoint MQ Broker API.

Comment: I tried that too but it was not working ! Even I referred the same.